# How to prove this sequence is Cauchy

Tags: real-analysis

Show directly (from the definition) that if

$$x_n=1+\frac{1}{2!} + \frac{1}{3!} + \ldots + \frac{1}{n!}\;,$$

then $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $n>m$.

$$\begin{align}|x_n - y_m| = \Big|\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k!} - \sum_{l=1}^{m} \frac{1}{l!}\Big| &= \Big|\sum_{k=m+1}^{n} \frac{1}{k!}\Big| < \Big|\sum_{k=m+1}^{n} \frac{1}{2^{k-1}}\Big| \\ &< \Big|\sum_{k=m+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{k-1}}\Big|= \Big|\frac{\frac{1}{2^{m+1}}}{1-\frac{1}{2}}\Big| = \frac{1}{2^{m}} \end{align} $$

Comment: $x_n$ are the partial sums... And what is $y_m$?

Comment: ym is another partial sums. By definition of Cauchy sequences: A sequence X=(xn) of real number is said to be a Cauchy sequence if for every ε>0 there exists a natural number H(ε) such that for all natural numbers n, m >= H(ε), the terms xn, xm satisfy |xn-xm|< ε.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, Maroja!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

As you yourself has commented, the useful tip here is $n!>2^{n-1}$.

Compute $|x_p-x_q|$ given that $p>q$. Check that this tends to $0$ when $q\to\infty$ no matter how far $p$ and $q$ are.

(The hint -that is, *my* hint- is expressend in a deliberately informal way).

Comment: How can I prove it towards to 0?